# reusable JQuery ajax GET by passing a variable

Tags: jquery, get, reusability

From the browser, when a user clicks a button or link (out of a large list A to ZZZ), I'm trying to GET an HTML fragment (predefined) back from the server.

1) Whats ***the most reusable way to perform AJAX GET's instead of coding them all over the place.***

The list of buttons could grow sequentially.

Comment: what code have you got currently as an example? and what do you expect to do with the fragment coming back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that I would do it personally is to use the [JQueryUi Widgets](https://jqueryui.com/widget/).

You could then do something fabulous like this - of course there are a million variations so use this as an idea and modify it to suit.

```
<div id="TargetElement">Empty</div>

<button role="reloader" data-get-url="http://www.google.com" data-get-target-id="#TragetElement">A special button or link.</button>
```

Then the widget:

```
$.widget( "custom.reloader", {

      _create: function() {

        var element = $(this);

          element.click(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();

             var getUrl = element.data('get-url');
             var target = element.data('get-target-id')

             $.get( getUrl, function( data ) {
              $(target).html( data ); 
            });

          });
      },

    });
```

And just call `$('[role=reloader]').reloader();` in onload or something to apply to all buttons of that role

:D

(not tested, but should work)